# Distributions and Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

I am confused about the relation between random variables and probability distributions in applications.

Let $\Omega$ be a probability space. Often, $\Omega$ is some measure space that is turned into a  probability space by a probability distribution. Assume that $\Omega$ is $\mathbb R$ with a probability distribution $f$. Let $X$ be a random variable on $\Omega$. Then, the image of $X$ can be thought of as a probability space by defining the probability of a measurable subset $Y$ in its image to be
$$
\int_{X^{-1}(Y)} X \cdot f.
$$
Furthermore, now that the image of $X$ is considered a probability space, there exists a probability distribution $g$ that defines it, i.e., for each measurable subset $Y$ in the image of $X$,
$$
\int_{X^{-1}(Y)} X \cdot f = \int_{Y} g.
$$

What is an example (a real-world application) of when one cares about each of these objects, i.e., when would one want to defined a probability distribution on $\mathbb R$, then a random variable and then the probability distribution on the image of that random variable?

Comment: I dont understand what are you asking, can you be more clear? What means for you "care" in this context?

Comment: “...measure space turned into a probability space by a probability distribution”—this sounds odd. Don’t we usually start with a given probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathbb{P})$ (a measure space that is normalized: $\mathbb{P}(\Omega)=1$) and then we are given some RV $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. a measurable map of the sample space. The composition of the probability measure and the inverse image then defines the distribution or law of $X$: for $\mathbb{P}\circ X^{-1}: \mathscr{B}\to [0,1]$ which is determined by its values on the sets $(-\infty,x]$ leading us to the CDF of $x$

Comment: While on the other hand given a function $G$ satisfying the properties that characterize a CDF we may define a random variable on a given sample space whose CDF is $G$. This is basic and probably all redundant to you but it’s not exactly clear what you’re getting at exactly.

Comment: @Masacroso You can interpret *cares* any way that you want.

Comment: @NapD.Lover The normalization often comes from a probability distribution on a measure space.

Comment: @LinearGuy the definition and formalism of random variables is a direct consequence of our interpretation of measure something. It is unavoidable in the same way that the formal definition of the real numbers, that is, we need some formalism of any mathematical object to study it behavior and develop theorems. Theorems are after applied to do calculus. By example in probability theory we need approximations to compute efficiently probabilities, and for this task we need theorems of approximations, etc., that are consequences of the formal definitions, not this time of our intuition.

Comment: so in mathematics there are two very different steps: first our intuition guide us to create some formal definition, and after we use the formalism to go beyond the capabilities of our intuition. In any case it doesn't care that the created mathematics would be "real" or not, what only cares is that it would be consistent, and so when we do calculus we get valid answers applicable in the real world

Answer (score 1):

I think the essence of your question is the following:

> What is the point of using random variables if everything will boil
>   down to a distribution in the end?

My personal feeling is that in the limited situation you are describing (when the measure space is $\Omega=\mathbb R$ and only allowed to consider one random variable at a time taking values in $\mathbb R$) there is indeed not that much to be gained by using random variables, other than convenience of notation.

However, working with random variables becomes essential on $\mathbb R^n$ for $n>1$, and I bet you are already encountering this case in practical applications without realizing it. For instance, any time you want to consider/compare two random variables on the same probability space, you are actually working with a random element of $\mathbb R^2$. This is the idea behind the concept of [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(probability)). Indeed, just to describe the marginal law of a random variable $X$ given the joint distribution $(X,Y)$ requires random variables.

This is the point in the post where I will start using notations from measure theory, the rigorous foundation for modern probability - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory#Measure-theoretic_probability_theory) if you are not familiar with this notation.

Going back to the previous example, to describe the marginal law of a random variable $X$ given its joint distribution $(X,Y)$ with some other random variable $Y$, one must make use of a (measurable) mapping between measure spaces - in this case, $\mathbb R^2$ equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and a measure (perhaps given by a density similar to how you described, or perhaps not) and a mapping to $\mathbb R$ given by projecting onto the first coordinate.

Typically in a first-year graduate course in probability, one starts by learning measure theory then transitioning into probability theory - with the transition point usually being the moment that independence is introduced. Of course, independence can be studied purely in the context of measure theory under the name of "product measures", but much of the intuition is lost without thinking in terms of random variables. And this point is also the moment when the power/usefulness of working with random variables, and not just with distributions, comes into its own.

Now to wildly extrapolate the essence of your question to a much broader context. Many classes of mathematical objects can be categorized in a systematic way - not surprisingly, called [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory) - with probability being no exception. Categories have objects, and maps between objects (one famous example being the category whose objects are sets, and whose mappings are functions). One can consider a category whose objects are probability spaces $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$, and whose mappings are random variables (more precisely, random elements - since people typically reserve "random variable" for the case when the codomain is $\mathbb R$). From this perspective, the reason we care about random variables is the same reason we care about mappings in any category: even if the most "tangible" part of a category is its objects, all the most interesting stuff happens in the mappings between them. This is why (in my opinion) probabilists seem to talk a lot more about random variables than about probability distributions.